# Can;t set placeholder in multiselect using this attr title

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

on my website i've use jquery multiselect to display selects as nice dropdowns. For some reason i cannot set multiselect placeholder using attributes/ or data added to select. Static text works but i need to pass dynamic placeholders names. Html looks like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="filter_select" id="front_type_filter" data-translation="Typ frontu" title="test123" name="front_type">
<option value="1">Płyta laminowana</option>
<option value="2">Płyta MDF foliowana</option>
<option value="3">Płyta MDF lakier</option>
<option value="4">Płyta MDF akryl</option>
<option value="5">Płyta fornirowana</option>
</select>
```

And js calling multiselect:

```
 $('.filter_select').multiselect({
    texts: {
            placeholder: $(this).attr('title'),
    },
});
```

On page there are multiple selects with same class with different titles/data-translation fields. Widget itself is working but with empty placeholder:

[image]

[image]

I have tried also access by  $(this).data('translation') - with same effect - no placeholder.  Only one thing worked for me but it was problematic - calling without using this - $("#someId").data('translation') - but also it's not dynamic at all.

Is there any good reason why it's not working?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `this` refers to the outer scope in the settings object, not the current `.filter_select` element. To fix this you can use `each()` to explicitly loop through the elements and read the `title` attribute from them:

```
$('.filter_select').each(function() {
  $(this).multiselect({
    texts: {
     placeholder: this.title, // or $(this).prop('title'),
    },
  });
});
```